# Godot Engine 2.0.3: Could not play .ogv (Ogg Theora) video file with VideoPlayer in html5 format

Tags: c++, html, game-engine

I've been searching for this solution in Godot Forum with no luck!

I am able to play .ogv (Ogg Theora Video) file with VideoPlayer in godot internal editor, but unable to display it in the browser after importing project to html5 format.

These are the errors I've got:

```
[1;31mERROR: load: [0m[1mNo loader found for resource: res://video.ogv
[0;31m   At: core/io/resource_loader.cpp:218.[0m
```

These are my codes:

```
get_node("VideoPlayer").set_stream(load("res://video.ogv"))
get_node("VideoPlayer").play()
```

How can I play .ogv in html5 format in Godot Engine?
Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks